# Deriving an identity of Lorentz group representation

Tags: special-relativity, hilbert-space, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I have a representation of Lorentz group on Hilbert space by following rule:
$$|\alpha\rangle_{F'}=U(\Lambda)|\alpha\rangle_{F}$$
where $\Lambda $ is Lorentz transformation satisfying $$x^{\mu'}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}x^{\nu}$$
Also $$U(\Lambda \Lambda')=U(\Lambda)U(\Lambda') $$

For infinitesimal transformation, we have $$U(1+\omega)=1+\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}+O(\omega^2) $$
I have to prove the following identity $$U^{-1}(\Lambda)M^{\mu\nu}U(\Lambda)=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu}_{\sigma}M^{\rho\sigma}$$

Then hint is given that us the relation $U(\Lambda \Lambda')=U(\Lambda)U(\Lambda') $ and the transformation $\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda ' \Lambda$.

I don't understand even how to proceed. Am I suppose to assume $\Lambda '_{\mu \nu}=M_{\mu \nu}$ ?

Comment: I guess you mean to say $U^{-1}(\Lambda)M^{\mu\nu}U(\Lambda)=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho}\Lambda^{\color{red}\nu}_{\sigma}M^{\rho\sigma}$.

Comment: @expikx yeah it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to assume that the finite transformation is correct and derive the infinitesimal one from it. The infinitesimal transformation is given by the commutator
$$
[M^{\rho\sigma},M^{\mu\nu}] = \eta^{\rho\mu}M^{\sigma\nu} + \eta^{\sigma\nu}M^{\rho\mu}-\eta^{\sigma\mu}M^{\rho\nu} - \eta^{\rho\nu}M^{\sigma\mu}\,. \tag{1}\label{comm}
$$
The transformation is infinitesimal if
$$
\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu} =\delta^\mu_\nu + i\omega^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,,
$$
with $\omega$ small (i.e. only linear orders will be kept). So the transformation for $M$ reads
$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\rho}\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\sigma} M^{\rho\sigma} &= (\delta^\mu_\rho + i\omega^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\rho})(\delta^\nu_\sigma+ i\omega^\nu_{\phantom{\nu}\sigma}) M^{\rho\sigma}
\\&=
M^{\mu\nu} + i\omega^\mu_{\phantom\mu\rho}M^{\rho\nu} + i\omega^\nu_{\phantom\nu\sigma}M^{\mu\sigma} + O(\omega^2)
\\&\overset{?}{=}M^{\mu\nu} + \left[\tfrac{i}2\omega_{\rho\sigma}M^{\rho\sigma}, M^{\mu\nu}\right]  + O(\omega^2)\tag{2}\label{qm}
\,.
\end{align}
$$
The last line (the one with the question mark) is the one that we have to prove, namely that $U(1+\omega)$ written as you did in your post is actually generating the infinitesimal version of the transformation of $M$. I remind you why we are interested in the commutator:
$$
U(1+\omega) M \,U(1+\omega)^{-1} = e^{\tfrac{i}2 \omega\cdot M} M e^{-\tfrac{i}2 \omega\cdot M} = \tfrac{i}2(\omega\cdot M) M - \tfrac{i}2 M (\omega \cdot M) + O(\omega^2)\,.
$$
The last equality is the commutator in \eqref{qm}. So we now use \eqref{comm} to show that it works.
$$
\eqref{qm} -M^{\mu\nu}= \tfrac{i}2\left(\omega^\mu_{\phantom\mu\sigma} M^{\sigma\nu} + \omega_\rho^{\phantom\rho\nu} M^{\rho\mu} - \omega_\rho^{\phantom\rho\mu}M^{\rho\nu} - \omega^\nu_{\phantom\nu\sigma}M^{\sigma\mu}\right)\,.
$$
Now you see why I put the indices staggered: the antisymmetry property of $\omega$ states $\omega^\mu_{\phantom\mu\nu} = - \omega^{\phantom\nu\mu}_{\nu}$. The reason is that the only object which is actually defined is $\omega_{\mu\nu}$. Whereas the ones with mixed indices simply mean $\omega^\mu_{\phantom\mu\rho}=\eta^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\nu\rho}$ and $\omega^{\phantom\rho\mu}_{\rho}=\omega_{\rho\nu}\eta^{\nu\mu}$. So tidying up the formula above one finds
$$
\eqref{qm} - M^{\mu\nu} = i \omega^\mu_{\phantom\mu\sigma} M^{\sigma\nu} + i \omega^\nu_{\phantom\nu\rho} M^{\mu\rho}\,,
$$
as you see I combined the first and third term together, and also the second and last after swapping the indices in $M$. Then by renaming $\rho\leftrightarrow \sigma$ we obtain the line immediately above \eqref{qm} as we wanted to prove.

Comment: I think my main confusion is coming from the fact that I don't know what $M^{\mu \nu}$ actually is? Is it a Linear operator in Hilbert space or is it a c-valued number, for example, $M^{23}=1+i$? I have taken a look at the wiki and without doubt it's an operator but then I don't under the expansion of $U(1+\omega)$.

Comment: No no, $M^{\mu\nu}$ is a matrix, $(M^{\mu\nu})_{\rho\sigma}$ for fixed $\mu,\nu,\rho,\sigma$ is a number. You can think of it as acting on the infinite dimensional Hilbert space of states, but in the end it only rotates the Lorentz indices among themselves, so it is a finite dimensional linear operator.